# Keras: Different training and validation results on same dataset using batch normalization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have high classification on training but low classification on validation even though I am using the same dataset. This problem only occurred when using batch normalization. Am I implementing it correctly?

Code using batch normalization:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
directory = '../ImageFilter/Images/',
target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(16,
kernel_size=(3, 3),
strides=(2,2),
activation='relu',
input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',
metrics = ['accuracy'])
epochs = 100
patience = 6
n_images = 91
file_path = 'imageFilterCNN.hdf5'

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(file_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=patience, verbose=0, mode='auto')
tboard = TensorBoard('./logs')

model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=n_images// batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
callbacks=[checkpointer, earlystop, tboard],
validation_data=train_generator,
validation_steps=n_images// batch_size)
```

> Outputs:
>   Epoch 15/100 11/11 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0092 - acc: 1.0000 -
>   val_loss: 3.0321 - val_acc: 0.5568

Comment: And what is weird about these results? Training accuracy is always gonna be better than testing; do you have any reasons to expect generalization to be simple?

Comment: I'm testing on the same dataset that it is training on. So the results should be fairly similar which they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying batch normalization on the first (input) layer, which is most likely a mistake. Why would you do this? Your input are images and you know very well how to normalize your input - in fact that's what you're doing in the first line. It makes no sense to apply a normalization again.

Batch normalization is applied in hidden layers so that the data does not get too big or too small. There's no simple, universal way of doing this, hence this special layer as introduced by [Sergey Ioffe and Christian Szegedy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf).

Comment: Okay. I took out the batch normalization in the first layer. I am still getting the same problem. When I train and validate/test on the same dataset, my training results are much better than my testing results.

Comment: @mcudic Did you ever solve your problem? Can you include the versions of Keras and Tensorflow that you were using? As well as versions of CUDA and CuDNN?